# 6 star (David Star / david Shield) in asteriks and in string letters

Tags: c#, geometry

I would like to print a Star of David shape in a console application:

```
     *
    * *
 * * * * *  
  * * * * 
 * * * * *
    * *
     *
```

I would like to support two modes:

1. Given an integer N, draw the star using N asterisks.
2. Given a string S, draw the star using the characters in the string.

Here's what I currently have:

```
static void Triangle(int nBase)
{
    int i, j, move;
    for (i = 1; i <= nBase; i++)
    {
        move = 0;
        do
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
            move++;
        } while (move <= nBase * 3 - i + 1);
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            Console.Write("* ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
static void TriangleInverted(double nBase)
{
    int i, j, move;
    for (i = (int)nBase; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        move = 0;
        do
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
            move++;
        } while (move <= nBase * 3 - i + 1);
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            Console.Write("* ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

As you can see I can draw a triangle and an inverted triangle (as per mode 1) but I don't know how to combine them into a star of david (which is basically having them overlapped properly).

I am also unsure as to how to implement mode (2).

Just to clarify my questions: Given a number of asteriks I would like to know what is the height and the base size of the each of the 2 opposite triangles. And in addition, where to start printing the opposite triangle? and how many asteriks should be in each printed line?

Comment: actually this question is clear, he showed clearly what he wants to get

Comment: @Begueradj: Where do you see a question ?

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, it is on the first line

Comment: @Begueradj It's request, not question. We don't do requests.

Comment: The OP has explained the desired outcome and shown some code.  Wonderful.  There is sill nothing describing his _current results_ and how they _differ_ from his desired results.

Comment: although there is no question, we all know what he want to achieve. i think that any down-voter could just edit it and add a question to make it clear or run it and see the problem

Comment: @amitfarag Exactly, we understand the OP's _request_, there still is no question.

Comment: @chancea and we can understand that is it not working. we can assume that he is asking "where is my problem?". you dont have to provide code. let me try to fix it, hope it will re-open

Comment: @amitfarag You do realize asking _"Where is my problem?"_ is the same thing as _"Why isn't this code working"_ which is stated in the close reason that it's off topic

Comment: @chancea this argue will lead us to no where. he tried to do it, it 's not that he want us to do it for him. the idea is that he tried, he didn't ask us to do it for him

Comment: @amitfarag Currently this question is in form "I want to do ..., here is my current code, could you correct it?". This way of asking is not useful for anyone (maybe except OP), because people with same problems will not be able to find it with google or other searching engine, which is kind of point why we provide answers. Post should be in form "I want to do ..., my code looks like ... but [**problem description here**] happens". This little improvement is really important.

Comment: @Pshemo you are right, but instead of this arguing, should someone edit it? if you think that you can improve it, do it. it will do the best for everyone or as you say, it will be useful

Comment: @amitfarag it has been edited several times to cause downvoting. Whereas I saw thousands of questions without any effort to make even the phrases grammatically correct, but they are welcome

Comment: by the way, this shape is not 100% david star. it should be more like that: http://pastebin.com/fDSzt2ah less long and it should be equilateral triangle

Comment: @Pshemo I've made the necessary changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on this to understand the basic form for your first question:http://jsfiddle.net/steinair/d6pe977v/

```
    <html>
Width of David star: <input type=text size=2 id=starwidth onchange="check_and_draw();" value="5" />
<center>
    <div id=star></div>
</center>

<script>
function check_and_draw(){
  w=document.getElementById("starwidth").value;
  drawstar(w);
}

function writetxt(t){
    document.getElementById("star").innerHTML+=t;
}

function drawstar(w){
document.getElementById("star").innerHTML="<br>Star of David with width of "+w+" letters:<hr>";

h=Math.ceil(w/3);//since every phase is a third of the triangle
for (y=1;y<=h;y++){ //The first third of the upper triangle
    for (x=1;x<=y;x++){
     writetxt("A ");
    }
    writetxt("<br>");    
}

for (y=0;y<h;y++){ //The base of the lower triangle and 2nd third of the upper triangle
    for (x=(w-y);x>0;x--){
     writetxt("B ");
    }
    writetxt("<br>");    
}

//if width is not even = odd then draw another line in the middle:
if ( w % 2 ) {
    for (x=(w-y);x>0;x--){
     writetxt("C ");
    }
    writetxt("<br>");
}    


for (y=h;y>0;y--){ //The base of the upper triangle and 2nd third of the lower triangle
    for (x=(w-y)+1;x>0;x--){
     writetxt("D ");
    }
    writetxt("<br>");    
}

for (y=h;y>0;y--){ //The last third of the lower triangle
    for (x=y;x>0;x--){
     writetxt("E ");
    }
    writetxt("<br>");    
}
}

</script>
</html>
```

And this answers your 2nd question: http://jsfiddle.net/steinair/qo575L9d/

```
    <html>
String:
<input type=text size=30 id=starstring onchange="check_and_draw();" value="" />
<center>
    <div id=star></div>
</center>

<script>
function check_and_draw() {
    starstring = document.getElementById("starstring").value;
    w = starstring.length;
    drawstar(w, starstring);
}

function writetxt(t) {
    document.getElementById("star").innerHTML += t;
}

function drawstar(w, starstring) {
    var n = 0;
    var spacer = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    document.getElementById("star").innerHTML = "<br>Star of David from string '" + starstring + "' (" + w + " letters):<hr>";

    h = Math.ceil(w / 3); //since every phase is a third of the triangle

    for (y = 1; y <= h; y++) { //The first third of the upper triangle
        n = 0;
        for (x = 1; x <= y; x++) {
            charN = starstring.charAt(n);
            n++;
            writetxt(charN + spacer);
        }
        writetxt("<br>");
    }

    for (y = 0; y < h; y++) { //The base of the lower triangle and 2nd third of the upper triangle
        n = 0;
        for (x = (w - y); x > 0; x--) {
            charN = starstring.charAt(n);
            n++;
            writetxt(charN + spacer);
        }
        writetxt("<br>");
    }

    //if width is not even = odd then draw another line in the middle:
    if (w % 2) {
        n = 0;
        for (x = (w - y); x > 0; x--) {
            charN = starstring.charAt(n);
            n++;
            writetxt(charN + spacer);
        }
        writetxt("<br>");
    }


    for (y = h; y > 0; y--) { //The base of the upper triangle and 2nd third of the lower triangle
        n = 0;
        for (x = (w - y) + 1; x > 0; x--) {
            charN = starstring.charAt(n);
            n++;
            writetxt(charN + spacer);
        }
        writetxt("<br>");
    }

    for (y = h; y > 0; y--) { //The last third of the lower triangle
        n = 0;
        for (x = y; x > 0; x--) {
            charN = starstring.charAt(n);
            n++;
            writetxt(charN + spacer);
        }
        writetxt("<br>");
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

**One option** is to create a 2-dimensional array of where you'd like the stars to be positioned, then after they the array has been filled then iterate over it and write it to the screen. For example,

```
var points = new bool[10,10];
for (int x=0; x<10; x++)
for (int y=0; y<10; y++)
{
   if (x == y) points[x,y] = true;
}

for (int y=0; y<10; y++)
{
    for (int x=0; x<10; x++)
    {
       if (points[x,y]) Console.Write("*");
       else Console.Write(" ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

**Another option** is to use [SetCursorPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to position the cursor where you'd like the `*` to be written.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'll be grateful if you can see my clarification: ust to clarify my questions: Given a number of asteriks I would like to know what is the height and the base size of the each of the 2 opposite triangles. And in addition, where to start printing the opposite triangle? and how many asteriks should be in each printed line?

Comment: If you're looking for the exact offset\proportions for the triangles (i.e. equal base\height offset by 25% of total height) then you may have better luck asking on http://judaism.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is old but for coming developers.

The code maybe not beautiful but it's working.

`

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int size=20;
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
                     if((i+j>=size/2-1 && i<=size/2-1 && j-i<=size/2-1) ||
                        (i==size/5 && j<size-1)||
                        (i-j<=size/5 && j<size/2 && i>size/5)||
                        (i+j<=size+((size-10)/5) && j>=size/2 && i>size/5))
                         Console.Write("*");
                     else
                         Console.Write(" ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
```

`

Change the size as you want (preference to even numbers).